# Check value of ng-model against string and do function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-change

I have a few functions that I'm having to mix because of scope in a < select :

**HTML:**

```
<!-- COUNTRY -->

    <select class="account--select" type="text" name="country" ng-model="data.country_id"
            ng-options="o.code as o.name for o in content.countries" ng-change="reset();PookycountryChanged()">
        <option value="">OTHER*</option>
    </select>
```

**Directive:**

```
scope.PookycountryChanged = function() { 
           scope.$watch('data.country_id', function(){
                if ('data.country_id' == "OTHER*") {
                    console.log('this is the other option selected');
                }
           });
        }
```

**AIM:**
To be able to have a function run when the value of the option selected is equal to 'OTHER*'. Right now this is set to a simple console.log. Getting nothing in the console at the momento.

Any pointers?

**UPDATE with Reset() function:**

```
scope.reset = function(){
            scope.isenabled = (scope.data.country_id == content.config.pca_country);
            scope.country = _.findWhere(scope.content.countries, {code : scope.data.country_id});
        };
        scope.reset();
```

**UPDATE 2:** 
Generated markup:

```
<select ng-change="reset()" ng-options="o.code as o.name for o in content.countries" ng-model="data.country_id" name="country" type="text" class="account--select ng-scope ng-valid ng-dirty"><option value="" class="">OTHER*</option><option value="0" selected="selected">United Kingdom</option></select>
```

Comment: Can you post a fiddle please?

Comment: Not easily, the stack is a monster. Apologies I know it's annoying.

Just a thought. Can I not append an attribute to the option in the select? An ID or something?

Or have the data.id_country == "" because the option in the markup has no value?

Comment: The function provided in your `scope.$watch` will be called automatically whenever the given value is changed, you don't need (or want to) manually call it.

Comment: first: in `PookycountryChanged` you not check value for `data.country_id` just create yet another watch, second: in watch you compare string `'data.country_id'` with string `"OTHER*"` so it always _false_.  Also can you provide function `reset`?

Comment: @HarryL, can you explain why in function `PookycountryChanged` that called on change, you create watch instead a simple checking value?

Comment: @HarryL, do you really need save `data.country_id` instead get `country` object at once?

Comment: @Grundy this might help. Here is the generated markup:

<select ng-change="reset()" ng-options="o.code as o.name for o in content.countries" ng-model="data.country_id" name="country" type="text" class="account--select ng-scope ng-valid ng-dirty"><option value="" class="">OTHER*</option><option value="0" selected="selected">United Kingdom</option></select>

Comment: add this in original post, and also it would be greate if you can provide plunker or jsfiddle with working sample :-) i mean sample only for reproduce your problem

Comment: @Grundy popped this in the question. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82712/discussion-between-grundy-and-harry-l).

Comment: What are you trying to do?  It looks like you're changing the model value every time the select is changed.  Can you just explain in plain language what you want to have happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now you have a few problems with your code: in `PookycountryChanged` you not check value for `data.country_id` just create yet another *watch*, also in watch you compare string 'data.country_id' with string "OTHER*" so it always false.

In case where you select item with `value=""` model set value to `null` so in watch function you can check it like in snippet below.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.reset = function() {
      $scope.isenabled = ($scope.data.country_id == $scope.content.config.pca_country);
      $scope.country = _.findWhere($scope.content.countries, {
        code: $scope.data.country_id
      });
    };
    $scope.content = {
      config : {pca_country: 3},
      countries: [{
        code: 1,
        name: 'name1'
      }, {
        code: 2,
        name: 'name2'
      }, {
        code: 3,
        name: 'name3'
      }, {
        code: 4,
        name: 'name4'
      }, {
        code: 5,
        name: 'name5'
      }, {
        code: 6,
        name: 'name6'
      }, {
        code: 7,
        name: 'name7'
      }]
    };
    $scope.$watch('data.country_id', function(newVal) {
      if (newVal === null) {
        console.log('selected others');
      }
    })
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <select class="account--select" type="text" name="country" ng-model="data.country_id" ng-options="o.code as o.name for o in content.countries" ng-change="reset();">
    <option value="">OTHER*</option>
  </select>
{{country}}
</div>
```

Or you can avoid even your reset function

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.content = {
      config: {
        pca_country: 3
      },
      countries: [{
        code: 1,
        name: 'name1'
      }, {
        code: 2,
        name: 'name2'
      }, {
        code: 3,
        name: 'name3'
      }, {
        code: 4,
        name: 'name4'
      }, {
        code: 5,
        name: 'name5'
      }, {
        code: 6,
        name: 'name6'
      }, {
        code: 7,
        name: 'name7'
      }]
    };
    $scope.$watch('data.country_id', function(newVal, oldVal) {
      if (newVal !== oldVal && !newVal) {
        console.log('selected others');
      }
    })
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <select class="account--select" type="text" name="country" ng-model="country" ng-options="o.name for o in content.countries" ng-change="data.country_id=country.code;isenabled=country.country_id==content.config.pca_country">
    <option value="">OTHER*</option>
  </select>
  {{country}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove `PookycountryChanged()` from your `ng-change`, then remove the function wrapping your `$watch`. There is no point having a watcher inside a function since the watch will always be running anyways.

Also change your option to this:

```
<option value="OTHER*">OTHER*</option>
```

Then you need to remove the quotation marks around `data.country_id`:

```
scope.$watch('data.country_id', function(){
  if (data.country_id === "OTHER*") {
    console.log('this is the other option selected');
  }
});
```

Comment: It will be causing problems. This is, however, not an answer to the question.

Comment: Mmm, that will mess with the data that's filling the value attr and will only have one dropdown to be able to be selected. If you look at the generated markup in the latest update in my question that will make more sense.